# VBA vlookup formula second value

Tags: excel, vba, range, vlookup, lookup

Hi I have problem about vlookup in VBA . I have the followings:

```
Cell A10=subtotal  , Cell C10= 22

Cell A40=subtotal , Cell C40= 14

Cell A88=subtotal , Cell C88 = 1000
```

In CellB56, using vlookup to get the value 14. The formula is =vlookup(“subtotal”,A:C,3,0). But it only show 22.

In CellB89, using vlookup to get the value 1000. The formula is = vlookup (“subtotal”,A:C,3,0). But it only show 22.

Do anyone have suggestion how to use vlookup about this question?

Regards,
Joe

Comment: can you post a screenshot  of  both Sheet, Its better to see it than visualizing  it.

Comment: Sorry Zen, I am new learner of this website and do not know how to add the file or visualization from the phone. I think vlookup cannot find the value of second time of “subtotal”. Is there any excel formula eg indirect & vlookup together to get the results of second and thirds subtotal of vlookup

Answer (score 0):

Two more straightforward solutions:

You could rename the cells in column A to be unique, so maybe put A40 as 'subtotal2' and A88 as 'subtotal3'. Then change the formula in B56 to `=VLOOKUP("subtotal2",A:C,3,0)` and B89 to `=VLOOKUP("subtotal3",A:C,3,0)`.

If you don't want to rename the cells in column A, you could add a helper column in column D - perhaps '1st' in D10, '2nd' in D40 and '3rd' in D88. Then change the formula in B56 to `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"subtotal",D:D,"2nd")` and D88 to `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"subtotal",D:D,"3rd")`.